# systemd. Журнал пользователя перенаправляется в системный

Tags: linux, логирование, systemd

Добавил сессию пользователя через `user@imya.service`. У пользователя пара служб в `.config/systemd/user/`. Так вот вывод логов я не вижу в `journalctl --user`, а вижу в `journalctl -u user@imya`. Но если залогиниться вручную, то вроде пишет куда нужно.

Comment: А там полные пути указаны?

Comment: Где полные пути?

Comment: Ну до логов. Или я чё-то упустил?

Comment: Логи в журнале. Не в файлах